# How to update field with file's last saved timestamp in MSAccess?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, timestamp

Building a data historian in MS Access which pulls data from excel files which are periodically overwritten with fresh data cuts (a.k.a. snapshots).  Added an annotation column into the DB to hold the timestamp of when the snapshot was taken.  Seeking to use the excel file's last saved date/timestamp as the entry into this column.

Possible in SQL within a Query?
If not, what about a VBA mod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the custom function below:

```
Function FileLastModified(strFullFileName As String)
    Dim fs As Object, f As Object

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.GetFile(strFullFileName)

    FileLastModified = f.DateLastModified

    Set fs = Nothing
    Set f = Nothing
```

Here is the usage:

```
If FileLastModified("C:\test.txt") > DateAdd("h", -12, Now()) Then <...your update code...>
```

Reference: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=215588

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in VBA using the FileSystemObject and using the File object's DateLastModified property.

```
Dim sFileName
Dim objFSO

sFileName = "C:\file.xls" ' Read this value from your database

Set objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(sFileName)
```

At this point you can read the file's [DateLastModified property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datelastmodified-property):

```
objFile.DateLastModified
```

You can then update your record accordingly.